# multiple tiff images to pdf with python

Tags: python, pdf, img2pdf

I have a image file list and I would like to generate a single output.pdf file with these images.

The following code works with one image file only (here the first element of image_list):

```
with open("output.pdf","wb") as f, io.BytesIO() as output:
    img = Image.open(image_list[0])
    img.save(output, format='tiff')
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(output.getvalue()))
```

How can I adapt this code to work with the complete list of image files ?

I tried :

```
with open("output.pdf","wb") as f, io.BytesIO() as output:
        img = Image.open(image_list[0])
        img.save(output, format='tiff')
        img2 = Image.open(image_list[1])
        img2.save(output, format='tiff')
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(output.getvalue()))
```

but it doesn't work (the created pdf contain only the last image, ie image_list[1])

Answer (score 2):

A possible hack could be to run it through [ImageMagick's](https://imagemagick.org) `convert`:

```py
import os
os.system('convert '+' '.join(image_list)+' output.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response !The final goal is a standalone executable file generated with pyinstaller --onefile. So the .exe file could be executed from anyone. Your solution does the job but I would prefer a solution without running a command line. I wish I could find one.

Comment: Try Python Wand. Though it requires ImageMagick. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/

Comment: In this case, I think I would prefer to generate one pdf per tiff file and merge the pdfs as it doesn't require to install ImageMagick on each computer when sharing the program.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally used the following code :

```
for i in....     
            # Create one pdf file per tiff file
            with open(str(i) + '.pdf', "wb") as f, io.BytesIO() as output:
                img = PIL.Image.open(str(i) + '.tiff')
                img.save(output, format='tiff')
                f.write(img2pdf.convert(output.getvalue()))

# merge the pdf file into one output pdf file
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

output_file = publication_number + ".pdf"
file_list = os.listdir()
pdf_list = []
for file in file_list:
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf_list.append(file)
pdf_list.sort(key=lambda f: int(
    ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, f))))  # trier la liste d'image du plus petit au plus grand (et pas 1, 10, 11, 2, 3)

for pdf_file in pdf_list:
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))
with open(output_file, 'wb') as fh:
    pdf_writer.write(fh)

for i in range(1, max_page + 1):  
    os.remove(str(i) + '.tiff')
    os.remove(str(i) + '.pdf')
```